# C++: Checking to see who won Tic-Tac-Toe Game

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I need to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have to write a function that basically figures out who won in a Tic-Tac-Toe game. If X won, I return 0, Y, return 1, and if neither won, return 2.

The only things given to me were the struct definition, and the function prototype. I'm not sure how to implement the "moves" variable into this program, and I'm also unsure how to return 2, if neither player won. I thought for a second to put it after the else if's, but then it would almost always return 2, since the previous conditions would probably rarely be met. I'm also finding that I am returning 0, even when Y wins. Sigh...Spent so much time taking a 5-unit Calculus class during my winter vacation, that it has made my coding rusty as heck!

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct TTT{
char array[3][3];
unsigned moves;
};

unsigned whoHasWon( const TTT & game );

int main()
{


    TTT x = {{{'X','O',' '}, {' ','X',' '}, {'O',' ','X'}}, 5};
    TTT y = {{{'X','O',' '}, {'X','O',' '}, {' ','O',' '}}, 4};

    cout << whoHasWon( x );

    cout << whoHasWon( y );

    return 0;
}

unsigned whoHasWon( const TTT & game )
{

    //First check diagonals

    if (game.array[0][0] == 'X' && game.array[1][1] == 'X' &&
        game.array[2][2] == 'X')
    {
        return 0;
    }

    else if (game.array[0][0] == 'O' && game.array[1][1] == 'O' && 
             game.array[2][2] == 'O')
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if (game.array[2][0] == 'X' && game.array[1][1] == 'X' && 
        game.array[0][2] == 'X')
    {
        return 0;
    }

    else if (game.array[2][0] == 'O' && game.array[1][1] == 'O' && 
             game.array[0][2] == 'O')
    {
        return 1;
    }

    for (unsigned row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {                // Check rows

        if (game.array[row][0] == 'X' && game.array[row][1] == 'X' && 
            game.array[row][2] == 'X')
        {
            return 0;
        }

        else if (game.array[row][0] == 'O' && game.array[row][1] == 'O'  && 
                 game.array[row][2] == 'O')
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
    {        //Check columns
        if (game.array[0][column] == 'X' && game.array[1][column] == 'X' && 
            game.array[2][column] == 'X')
        {
            return 0;
        }

        else if (game.array[0][column] == 'O'     && game.array[1][column] == 'O' && 
                 game.array[2][column] == 'O')
        {
           return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The logic looks OK, although the code is a little long. You are missing a `return 2;` at the end, that's all.

Comment: Thank you...Can you give me a general idea as to how this could be shortened?

Comment: Make a function `bool hasWon(const TTT & game, char ch)` which checks if `ch` is in any of the rows, columns, or diagonals. This should be roughly half of your code. Then call this function twice from your `whoHasWon` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (game.array[0][column] == 'O' && game.array[1][column] == 'O' && 
        game.array[2][column] == 'O')
{
    return 0;
}
```

should be

```
if (game.array[0][column] == 'O' && game.array[1][column] == 'O' && 
        game.array[2][column] == 'O')
{
    return 1;
}
```

Also there should be `return 2;` at the end, in case neither won.

Comment: Thank you! I got it now.